# How do I print each month with its number?

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

def main():

```
x = eval(input("Enter the number of the month you wish to know how much you have: "))
for month in (1, 2, 3, 4):
    print("for this month 1 you have" , month * 10 , "dollar")
```

main()

I'm trying to get this result once run:

Please enter the number of days:  4
Month 1:  $10
Month 2:  $20
Month 3:  $30
Month 4:  $40

I'm having problem numbering each line of the month :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your code read as:

```
print("for this month {month} you have".format(month=month) , month * 10 , "dollar")
```

The real magic is Python's `.format()`. You can read more about it in the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples).

You could also just have: `"for this month {} you have".format(month)`

Comment: Glad I could help you out! Please mark my answer as accepted if I correctly answered your question.